# c++, Base class constructor seperate declearation and implementation

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor, derived-class

In my C++ program I have separate .h and .cpp files and everything is working so far except when I want to use a base class constructor for a derived class. It is working but only if I put the function definition if the class deceleration.
Here's the working code for the .h file.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class property
{
    public:
        property();
        property(const property & src);
        property(int src);
        ~property();
        virtual int disp() const = 0;
        int get_ownable();          
    private:

    protected:

        int ownable;
};

class rr : public property
{
    public:
    rr();
    rr(const rr & src);
    rr(int src):property(src)
    {cout << "\nderived class was called\n";};
    ~rr();

    virtual int disp() const;       
    private:    
    protected:      
};
```

The imp.cpp (implementation) file is

```
#include "head.h"

#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


//property class implimentations

property::property()
{
    ownable = 0;
}


property::property(const property & src)
{
    ownable = src.ownable;
}



property::property(int src)
{
    ownable = src;
    cout << "\nparent class called\n";
}

property::~property()
{

}

int property::get_ownable()
{
    return ownable;
}

rr::rr()
{}
rr::rr(const rr & src)
{
    ownable = src.ownable;
}




/*
rr::rr(int src):property(src)
{
    cout << "\nderived class was called\n";
}
*/



rr::~rr()
{
}
int rr::disp() const
{
}
```

There is other code but it is working fine and not connected to this. The output is

```
parent class called
derived class was called
```

So that works just fine but if I un-comment out the function in the .imp file and remove the declaration in the .h

```
    rr(int src):property(src);
```

I get the error

```
head.h: IN constructor 'rr::rr(int)':
head.h 113: error: expeted '{' at end of input
imp.cpp: at global scope:
imp.cpp:348:error: redefiniton of 'rr::rr(int);
head.h.113: error: 'rr::rr(int); previousle defined here
```

All the examples I can find on line of how to do this do it with all the functions defined in the class declaration. I can't find any examples of how to do it with 2 files. Can anyone tell me how to define the base class constructor call in a separate file?
I am on a Linux system using g++ compiler.

Comment: Construction initializer list is part of the implementation, not the declaration. In other words, it goes together with constructor body. You can either put both into .h file, or both into .cpp file; you can't separate them.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**BaseClass.h**

```
#pragma once

class BaseClass {
public:
    BaseClass(int a);

private:
    int a_private;
};
```

**BaseClass.cpp**

```
#include "BaseClass.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

BaseClass::BaseClass(int a) {
    cout << "Base class constructor called" << endl;
    this->a_private = a;
}
```

**Derived.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "BaseClass.h"

class Derived : public BaseClass {
public:
    Derived(int a);
private:
    int a_private;
};
```

**Derived.cpp**

```
#include "Derived.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

Derived::Derived(int a) : BaseClass(a) {
    cout << "Derived class constructor called" << endl;
    this->a_private = a;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "BaseClass.h"
#include "Derived.h"

int main() {
    Derived d(2);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with the command 
`g++ main.cpp Derived.cpp BaseClass.cpp` and running will result in the following output

```
Base class constructor called
Derived class constructor called
```

As mentioned in the comments (credits @IgorTandetnik), initializer lists should be used only in the implementation file. Not in the header file (provided the class is not templated).